# Populate ListView from List<String[]>

Tags: android

I am getting data in List. It is in the following format.

```
          AAA  123  456
          BBB  235  156
          CCC  458  425
```

I would like to display first column in the listview.

```
    ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.out_listtext); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listitem, acNames.get(0));
    list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

This displays firstrow. How do I display first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to create separate list for first column.

```
List<String> firstColumn = new ArrayList<String>();
for (List<String> row : acNames) {
    firstColumn.add(row.get(0));
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listitem, firstColumn);
```

EDITED

```
List<String> firstColumn = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String[] row : acNames) {
    firstColumn.add(row[0]);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listitem, firstColumn);
```

Comment: I am geting data in List<String []> format. Can I create sepate list from that ?